# Write buffer list to file

Tags: vimscript, buffers

I would like to have a file that contains all files that I opened with vim in the past. I know that there is the viminfo file but I want to have just a file with the filenames.

For this I would like to write the list of open buffers with `autocmd VimLeave` to a file.

I tried `:ls | w >> test.txt` but this does not work correctly.

Comment: `I know that there is the viminfo file` Do you also know that there's `:oldfiles` command? Doesn't it make the whole idea of having "an own file" useless?

Comment: That does sound like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/288754) maybe you should ask a question about what you want to do with this list of files and there is probably a better solution to use it than writting it by yourself :)

Comment: I wonder if sessions would be useful to you

Answer (score 2):

You can have all buffer names that haven't been unloaded (or wiped out?) with:

```
let files = filter(map(range(1,bufnr('$')), 'bufname(v:val)'), '!empty(v:val)')
```

You can save it with

```
call writefile(files, '/path/to/filename.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `redir` command (`:h redir`)

For example:

```
func! MyRedir() abort
    redir! > ~/test.txt
    :ls
    redir END
endfunc

augroup save_files | au!
    au VimLeave * call MyRedir()
augroup end
```

Comment: Or oldfiles instead of ls

Comment: There's also [`execute()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#execute%28%29), which I often find more convenient than `:redir`, especially for a single command...

Answer (score 1):

I took [Luc Hermitte's helpful answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21998/32634) and improved it somewhat.

1. It was returning unlisted (previously deleted) buffers, which isn't what I wanted. It now filters on `buflisted(v:val)`, rather than on `!empty(v:val)`.
2. I've added two commands:

   - `Lssave`: saves the unsorted buffer list as-is
   - `LSsave`: saves a sorted version of the buffer list
3. `mkdir` the output file's path, in case it doesn't already exist.

```bash
function s:bufferList()
    let l:bufferRange = range(1,bufnr('$'))
    let l:bufferList = map(l:bufferRange, 'bufname(v:val)')
    let l:bufferListListed = filter(l:bufferList, 'buflisted(v:val)')
    return l:bufferListListed
endfunction

command Lssave
    \ let s:bufferList = s:bufferList() |
    \ call mkdir("/path/to", "p", 0740) |
    \ call writefile(s:bufferList, "/path/to/filename.txt")

command LSsave
    \ let s:bufferList = s:bufferList() |
    \ let s:bufferListSorted = sort(s:bufferList) |
    \ call mkdir("/path/to", "p", 0740) |
    \ call writefile(s:bufferListSorted, "/path/to/filename.txt")
```

Comment: Are you sure about returning `$varname` instead of `l:varname`?

Comment: BTW, no need to pollute script variables with a static list of filenames. Also all these functions mutate their parameter. Even if having multiple variables may seem clearer, in the end they will all be the same identical variable, which may lead to confusing debugging sessions. That's why I did everything in one line (with an old syntax; you may assume lambdas nowadays).

Comment: An interesting improvement would be to read the pathname as an optional parameter for the command.

Comment: You will want to filter on `!empty(bufname) && buflisted` as unnamed buffers (like the ones we get on new vim sessions, or on `:new`, `:tabnew`, and so on) will be listed and don't make sense. With the new syntax, it's (IIRC): `range(1, bufnr('$'))->filter({_,v -> buflisted(v) && !empty(bufname(v))})->map({_,v -> bufname(v)})` (untested)

Comment: The bufferList() function above can be simplified by using the getbufinfo(#{buflisted: v:true}) call. Refer to https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#getbufinfo%28%29 for more information.

Comment: Luc, thank you very much for your feedback and expertise; it's well received. I'm a vimscript neophyte. When learning a new language, I often break down longer statements into little baby statements (sometimes with lots of variable names) in order to self-document. Multiple variables are certainly unnecessary. However, one of the reasons I used a variable at all is so that I could echo the value between statements to debug what was happening. However, I removed these echo statements in my posted answer. Is there a better method of debugging that you can possibly teach or point me to?